# Have django to automatically create database on "migrate"

Tags: django

In a development environment, there is a way to have django automatically create the database (on a postgreSQL server) on "migrate" command like it do when creating test database ?

My final goal is to have one database for each git branch.

Comment: Any solutions to this? I don't understand why when you do a "migrate" django automatically creates sqlite3 database but doesn't create a postgresql database

Answer (score 0):

You could script a script with pseudo code below

```
branch_name=<get branch name from git>
create_database with branch_name as db name
run django migrate
```

e.g. on Linux with bash it could be

```
branch_name=git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref HEAD
createdb ${branch_name}
python manage.py migrate
```

[The `createdb` command is from PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-createdb.html)

Then your Django settings.py also needs to change to use that DB name, for that you can read the Git branch name from Python in settings.py too:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> DBNAME = subprocess.check_output('git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref HEAD', shell=True)
>>> DBNAME.replace('\n', '')
'develop'
```

Then you can use that value in `settings.py` (above I am in a git branch `develop`)

Comment: I already retrieve the database name using environment variable. I just asked to know if django would be able to do that natively. If not I will do it manually before.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Django creates a database on "migrate". But only if it uses SQLite.
The documentation states it clearly
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial02/)

> **For databases other than SQLite**
>
> If you’re using a database besides SQLite, make sure you’ve created a database by this point. Do that with `CREATE DATABASE database_name;` within your database’s interactive prompt.
>
> ...
>
> If you’re using SQLite, you don’t need to create anything beforehand - the database file will be created automatically when it is needed.

Comment: Django should just create the database.  Ruby on Rails does this with the `rails db:create` command.

Answer (score -3):

No, because django is a *web framework*, not a web server, how you run that is up to you.

Also, having one database per git branch sounds like a nightmare, I'd hope that you are committing migrations and merging appropriately as required

Comment: Thanks for your response. We only need this in development environment. When working on a feature with database change on a specific branch we are stuck when changing to another branch because django "check" migration state. There is a recommended process ?

Comment: I guess its not something I've come across as a problem in all the time I've spent developing in django, I don't know if that is down to user process of making sure that branches are left in a stable condition before switching or something else. I guess the logical step would be a [git hook when creating a branch](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14297606/1324033) if that really is what you require