# git hook for first commit to a new branch

Tags: git, github

We use Git and Jira in my office.  Normally we use the create branch button to just create the branch.  I have 2 python files I run, 1 on when a branch is created and 1 when it is merged and subsequently deleted.

My question is:  How would I implement this as a hook for when a new branch is created (or first commit of a new branch) and when the branch is deleted?  I was thinking that it would go under either update or post-recieve.

```
#Script
python foo.py --create
python foo.py --delete
```

Its as simple as that, but im not sure which part of the life cycle it would go in while looking at the different hooks available.

I was reading update.sample, post-update.sample, etc.  I saw that in update.sample, there are two sections:

```
refs/heads/*,delete)
refs/heads/*,commit)
```

which i was thinking would be the sections i am interested in, given the variables referenced in those sections of code, but I was thinking that this could be a Local Commit / New Branch or Local Delete Branch, which doesnt work.  I wanted to do this for like i said, after it occurs on the server.

Comment: you can use the update hook, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297606/git-hook-when-a-new-branch-is-created-and-or-pushed

Comment: `update` hook is serve-side, it works on pushing.

Comment: So when looking at the *update* hook where do i place my create and delete script?  I saw a comment for delete branch and a flag for that, but is the new branch one right above it?  It just has a comment saying "Branch"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the exact parameters and conditions for the [update hook here](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks): it is a server-side hook, which means it will be triggered by a push to the Git repository hosting server.

If you are using an on premise instance of GitHub, you might need, as [described here](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.13/admin/guides/user-management/managing-global-webhooks/), to declare a [global webhook](https://developer.github.com/v3/enterprise-admin/global_webhooks/) instead, as you cannot easily add a hook on the server side when it comes to GitHub.