# How to use git hooks to bump version number when creating release branch?

Tags: git, githooks

I'm following the gitflow model for a data science project, and I would like to automatically change the version number inside one file and commit it, after creating a new release branch. The new version name should just be the name of the release branch.

I think the git hook for post-checkout is probably the best option, but I can't understand how to use the arguments it receives to check if the checkout was a branch creation or a checkout to an existing branch, nor how to get the name of the newly create release branch.

Comment: Automatic versioning perhaps may work, while better to have signed tag for each source release you do.

Comment: @0andriy How does automatic versioning works?

Comment: In a way you described it. I never use such approach and consider only (signed) tags.

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297606/git-hook-when-a-new-branch-is-created-and-or-pushed, you may want to try the update hook.

Comment: @alex it seems like that only works on pushing, since it's a server-side hook, and I would need it to be a local operation.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this with hooks?  Make a damn new-release script that starts a branch and bumps the version.

Comment: @jthill because I didn't want to change anything in the way things are done. Instead of creating a new script that I would call _instead_ of creating a new branch, I wanted to incorporate this in the regular workflow.

Answer (score 0):

It would make more sense to use pre-push or pre-commit to do this than post-checkout to avoid commits that contain only a version bump and no code changes. However, in terms of getting the version change done, you’ll need to be more specific about your code base. Is the version kept in a json file? Are you on a Unix? Windows?

Comment: I would actually prefer to to have it on checkout, and having a commit only for the version bump.

In terms of the codebase, I'm on Windows and have the version number inside a python script. I guess it actually makes more sense to keep the file in a standalone file, so I'm going to change that.